# Target button class in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have here a jquery which hides and collapse div when a button is pressed.

```
     jQuery('button').click( function(e) {
    jQuery('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

my problem is the button that is targeted by the jquery stands in all of the button of my page. how can i have tried targeting the button class but i've guest it doesnt work. Here is my html code.

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#claim-padala" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="claim-padala">
     Claim Smart Padala
  </button>
<! ––claim-padala ––>
<div class="collapse" id="claim-padala">
  <div class="card card-body">
   <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSe1V_P0INhaTJo2sfq8qrJTvo1UmWW8mpPIKWsZ93JUDj5h3A/formResponse" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');">

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>A. NOTE: Ang Digits Smart Padala Account Number ay 5577-5194-8194-0105 or Paymaya No. 0929-187-9421 kung nai-send na maki-Input ang Reference Number na nareceived na text from Paymaya or PYMYNegosyo</span>
        <input type="tel" name="entry.622619968" placeholder="Reference/Paymaya No." pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{16}|[0-9]{11}" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>B. Input ang amount na nareceived </span>
        <input type="number" name="entry.1812134286" placeholder="Received Amount" min="0" max="500000" step="any" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>C. Input your name </span>
        <input type="text" name="entry.1473350596" placeholder="Input Your Name" onkeypress='return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode == 32))' required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>D. Input your cellphone number. </span>
        <input type="tel" name="entry.741783283" placeholder="Input CP Number" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{11}" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

     <div class="form-element">
        <span>E. Input your address. </span>
        <input type="text" name="entry.1153333277" placeholder="Address" required="">
     </div>
     <br>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple:

```
jQuery('#my_btn').click( function(e) {
        jQuery('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    });
```

add a unique **id** to the button :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="my_btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#claim-padala" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="claim-padala">
     Claim Smart Padala
  </button>
<! ––claim-padala ––>
<div class="collapse" id="claim-padala">
  <div class="card card-body">
   <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSe1V_P0INhaTJo2sfq8qrJTvo1UmWW8mpPIKWsZ93JUDj5h3A/formResponse" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');">

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>A. NOTE: Ang Digits Smart Padala Account Number ay 5577-5194-8194-0105 or Paymaya No. 0929-187-9421 kung nai-send na maki-Input ang Reference Number na nareceived na text from Paymaya or PYMYNegosyo</span>
        <input type="tel" name="entry.622619968" placeholder="Reference/Paymaya No." pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{16}|[0-9]{11}" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>B. Input ang amount na nareceived </span>
        <input type="number" name="entry.1812134286" placeholder="Received Amount" min="0" max="500000" step="any" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>C. Input your name </span>
        <input type="text" name="entry.1473350596" placeholder="Input Your Name" onkeypress='return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode == 32))' required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>D. Input your cellphone number. </span>
        <input type="tel" name="entry.741783283" placeholder="Input CP Number" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{11}" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

     <div class="form-element">
        <span>E. Input your address. </span>
        <input type="text" name="entry.1153333277" placeholder="Address" required="">
     </div>
     <br>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can replace **my_btn** (id of the button) with your own custom id. Replace it in your both Jquery code and button too.

**EDIT**: You can apply this to three buttons (as mentioned in your comment) by using **class** instead of **id**. This is how you can do this:

```
jQuery('.my_btn').click( function(e) {
        jQuery('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    });
```

And this is your html code to do so.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary my_btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#claim-padala" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="claim-padala">
     Claim Smart Padala
  </button>
<!-- Added 2 buttons by me for demo purpose -->
 <button class="btn btn-primary my_btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#claim-padala" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="claim-padala">
   Claim Smart Padala
 Button 2  </button>
 <button class="btn btn-primary my_btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#claim-padala" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="claim-padala">
     Claim Smart Padala Button 3
  </button>
<!-- End added 2 buttons -->
<! ––claim-padala ––>
<div class="collapse" id="claim-padala">
  <div class="card card-body">
   <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSe1V_P0INhaTJo2sfq8qrJTvo1UmWW8mpPIKWsZ93JUDj5h3A/formResponse" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');">

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>A. NOTE: Ang Digits Smart Padala Account Number ay 5577-5194-8194-0105 or Paymaya No. 0929-187-9421 kung nai-send na maki-Input ang Reference Number na nareceived na text from Paymaya or PYMYNegosyo</span>
        <input type="tel" name="entry.622619968" placeholder="Reference/Paymaya No." pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{16}|[0-9]{11}" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>B. Input ang amount na nareceived </span>
        <input type="number" name="entry.1812134286" placeholder="Received Amount" min="0" max="500000" step="any" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>C. Input your name </span>
        <input type="text" name="entry.1473350596" placeholder="Input Your Name" onkeypress='return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode == 32))' required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>D. Input your cellphone number. </span>
        <input type="tel" name="entry.741783283" placeholder="Input CP Number" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{11}" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

     <div class="form-element">
        <span>E. Input your address. </span>
        <input type="text" name="entry.1153333277" placeholder="Address" required="">
     </div>
     <br>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have added 2 buttons more for demo purposes. You can remove it if you want. You can replace **my_btn** (class of the button) with your own custom class. Make sure you change it in your Jquery also. Hope it helps.

Comment: you could create a snippet and run it yourself, also allowing the OP to run it themselves

Comment: thank you for helping me sir, i have 3 buttons that will use that function, is it possible to target the button class?

Comment: I have edited the post. You can check it out and tell me whether it works or not.

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks like Bootstrap, which has the functionality for `collapse` baked in. As long as you're importing the bootstrap css and js you don't need that button `click` function.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#claim-padala" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="claim-padala">
     Claim Smart Padala
  </button>
<! ––claim-padala ––>
<div class="collapse" id="claim-padala">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSe1V_P0INhaTJo2sfq8qrJTvo1UmWW8mpPIKWsZ93JUDj5h3A/formResponse" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');">

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>A. NOTE: Ang Digits Smart Padala Account Number ay 5577-5194-8194-0105 or Paymaya No. 0929-187-9421 kung nai-send na maki-Input ang Reference Number na nareceived na text from Paymaya or PYMYNegosyo</span>
        <input type="tel" name="entry.622619968" placeholder="Reference/Paymaya No." pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{16}|[0-9]{11}" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>B. Input ang amount na nareceived </span>
        <input type="number" name="entry.1812134286" placeholder="Received Amount" min="0" max="500000" step="any" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>C. Input your name </span>
        <input type="text" name="entry.1473350596" placeholder="Input Your Name" onkeypress='return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode == 32))' required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>D. Input your cellphone number. </span>
        <input type="tel" name="entry.741783283" placeholder="Input CP Number" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{11}" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>E. Input your address. </span>
        <input type="text" name="entry.1153333277" placeholder="Address" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```